# get age_range from user in my app facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app, with 35000 users. How can I get each age_range(it's basic permissions) not during authorization(after a while)? If I don't have access_tokens of users, but all users install and approve my app?

I try

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{USER-ID}/?access_token=***
```

but it does not show me age_range

Answer (score 1):

The `age_range` field needs to be requested specifically:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{USER-ID}?fields=id,age_range&access_token={user_access_token}
```

should work in your case.

Comment: i dont save users access_tokens :(

Comment: But why did you write that you tried it with an request including the access token? If you have a Canvas or Page Tab app, do it like @Bruno suggested. Otherwise I think it's not possible if you don't collect the access tokens

Comment: i try it with my own access_token :P

Answer (score 0):

If your app was made to run on Canvas or is a Page Tab app, you can get the range age even if the user hasn't authorized yet by reading the `signed_request` parameter.

Read more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request#ageobject